# How to avoid printing the below autodetected configurations info on the logs file in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring-batch

How to avoid printing the below `autodetected` configurations info on the logs file in Spring Batch?

I used below, but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried few options but it did not worked well. Any quick pointers?

I am using logback.xml with the required dependencies.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

I also used below, still it doesn't worked out:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=off
```

**Log Traces -**

```
============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy', 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect', 'org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice', 'org.aspectj.weaver.AnnotatedElement'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher', 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'jobLauncher' (OnBeanCondition)


   BatchAutoConfiguration#jobExecutionExitCodeGenerator matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration#jobLauncherCommandLineRunner matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.batch.job.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration#jobOperator matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'safeDataSource', 'rdsDataSource', 'batchDataSource', 'edsDataSource', 'secondaryDWDataSource', 'primaryDWDataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   GenericCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GenericCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - HibernateEntityManager found class 'org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager' (HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.HibernateEntityManagerCondition)

   HibernateJpaConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'safeDataSource', 'rdsDataSource', 'batchDataSource', 'edsDataSource', 'secondaryDWDataSource', 'primaryDWDataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'safeDataSource', 'rdsDataSource', 'batchDataSource', 'edsDataSource', 'secondaryDWDataSource', 'primaryDWDataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.JdbcTemplateConfiguration#jdbcTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.NamedParameterJdbcTemplateConfiguration#namedParameterJdbcTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'jdbcTemplate'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jmx.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration#mbeanExporter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration#mbeanServer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.management.MBeanServer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration#objectNamingStrategy matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.ObjectNamingStrategy; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JtaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.transaction.Transaction'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jta.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration#persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.dao.exceptiontranslation.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SimpleCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration#platformTransactionManagerCustomizers matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'transactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'transactionManager' (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration#transactionTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   ActiveMQAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory', 'org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false) did not find property 'proxy-target-class' (OnPropertyCondition)

   ArtemisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory', 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   AtomikosJtaConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   BatchConfigurerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer' commonConfig (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   BatchConfigurerConfiguration.JpaBatchConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchConfigurerConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   BitronixJtaConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixContext' (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheManagerJpaDependencyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   CaffeineCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine', 'org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster', 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraReactiveDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster', 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.ReactiveCassandraTemplate', 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.ReactiveSession', 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.ReactiveCassandraRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.datastax.driver.core.Session', 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   CloudAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.cloud.config.java.CloudScanConfiguration' (OnClassCondition)

   CodecsAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.codec.CodecConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket', 'com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'com.couchbase.client.spring.cache.CouchbaseCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseReactiveDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.ReactiveCouchbaseRepository', 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.ReactiveCouchbaseRepository', 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration#transactionManager:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' transactionManager (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   EhCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'net.sf.ehcache.Cache', 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client', 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryDirectoryServer' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.mongodb.MongoClient', 'de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodStarter' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader', 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat', 'org.apache.coyote.UpgradeProtocol' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'io.undertow.Undertow', 'org.xnio.SslClientAuthMode' (OnClassCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' (OnClassCondition)

   FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'freemarker.template.Configuration', 'org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'groovy.text.markup.MarkupTemplateEngine' (OnClassCondition)

   GsonAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.google.gson.Gson' (OnClassCondition)

   H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.h2.server.web.WebServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance', 'com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler', 'org.springframework.http.server.reactive.HttpHandler' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter' (OnClassCondition)

   HypermediaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.hateoas.Resource', 'org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping', 'org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin' (OnClassCondition)

   InfinispanCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   InfluxDbAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.influxdb.InfluxDB' (OnClassCondition)

   IntegrationAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration' (OnClassCondition)

   JCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.cache.Caching', 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JodaDateTimeJacksonConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder', 'org.joda.time.DateTime', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DateTimeSerializer', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.JacksonJodaDateFormat' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule' (OnClassCondition)

   JerseyAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider', 'javax.servlet.ServletRegistration' (OnClassCondition)

   JestAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.searchbox.client.JestClient' (OnClassCondition)

   JmsAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.jms.Message', 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   JndiJtaConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnJndi JNDI environment is not available (OnJndiCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   JooqAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.jooq.DSLContext' (OnClassCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' entityManagerFactory and found beans of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' &entityManagerFactory (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#transactionManager:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' transactionManager (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration.JpaWebConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:

   WebClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' (OnClassCondition)

   XADataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: The auto-configuration report is turned on when you run your app with `--debug`. Are you running your app in debug mode?

Comment: @ Mahmoud Ben Hassine - No. I am just launching main method from the STS, or  from Spring Boot Dashboard provided by STS.

Comment: In this case, you should have set the `Enable debug output` option in your run configuration. If you deactivate this option from your spring boot app run configuration, you should not see the auto configuration report anymore.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Ben Hassine  - I did not set any of these options, not sure if its coming via the logback and logback-classic jars

Answer (score 0):

If your project has application.properties, set `debug=false`.

`debug=true` a.k.a `--debug` prints the autoconfig logs for springboot

Edit: Just noticed, you are using spring batch. See, there should be a same/similar property for the autoconfig logs